# Spark Linear Regression Feature Hashes

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, data-science, apache-spark-ml

I am trying to use Spark's LinearRegressionWithSGD to predict the price on an item by country & device. After looking at the [feature extraction section](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-feature-extraction.html) of Spark MLLib, I am a bit unclear as to how I should hash the features. An example record would be:

```
{"price": 3.37, "site_id" 12, "brand_id": 332, "brand_type": "axcssdsdac", "item_id": 36, "country": "US", "device": "mobile"}
```

I've tried several hashing techniques (ex. MurmurHash), but they all seem to get garbage weights (such as NAN, PositiveInfinity, etc) or weights that trend towards 10^200+. Has anyone had any success hashing labeled features in Spark MLLib?

Comment: Why and what do you need to hash?

Comment: It looks like what you need is more one-hot than hashing.

Answer (score 0):

Performing a **hash** on the country is likely to conflate unrelated observations.  You might be able to use a **simhash** on the device and an exact comparison (case insensitive) on the **country** -.  The hashing approach across ***both*** variables might  work well for **clustering** but not as likely for regression.

Create separate curves for each country and you might experiement with applying the **simhash** to the mobile device.